# What does Internal`InheritedBlock do?

Tags: functions, scoping, undocumented

What does the function `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` do? How is it different from the regular `Block`?

Comment: Popular use of this function started with Daniel's MathGroup post: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00710.html

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`` Internal`InheritedBlock `` (IIB) is similar to `Block`, except that it preserves the original definition of the function being passed to it. The function can then be modified as we wish inside the IIB without affecting the external definition.

Let's see how `Block` works first:

```
f[x_] := x
Block[{f},
    Print@DownValues[f];
    f[x_, y_] := x y;
    Print@DownValues[f];
];
Print@DownValues[f];

(* {} *)
(* {HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> x y} *)
(* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x} *)
```

You notice that the original definition of `f` is not available inside the `Block`. On the other hand, look at what IIB does:

```
f[x_] := x
Internal`InheritedBlock[{f}, 
    Print@DownValues[f];
    f[x_, y_] := x y;
    Print@DownValues[f];
];
Print@DownValues[f];

(* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x} *)
(* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x, HoldPattern[f[x_,y_]] :> x y} *)
(* {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x} *)
```

The original definition of `f` is available inside its scope, and new definitions are added to the existing ones (as is the usual behaviour), unless you explicitly clear them.

Comment: But is ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` faster or slower than `Block`/`Module` (when performing the same operation)?