# Copy Built-in function to new name

Tags: programming, function-construction, variable-definitions, core-language

It is know that some built-in functions are system function and changing their properties may cause trouble.

Suppose for example I want to change features of Cases:

```
SetAttributes[Cases, HoldFirst]
```

This will create a problem in MMA.

Is there a method to copy the built-in functions (for example Cases) so that the new named function can be used as if it is the built-in functions and then I can do whatever changes I want to the new function?

This works but creates problem in MMA:

```
Unprotect[Cases];
SetAttributes[Cases, HoldFirst];
Cases[1 + 3, _, {-1}]
(*{1, 3}*)
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
f = Cases;
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f[1 + 3, _, {-1}]
(*{4}*)
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: [(7912984)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7912984/618728), [(2793)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2793/121)

Answer (score 9):

### Basics

To get it out of the way, for the specific example given you could use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
Cases[Unevaluated[1 + 3], _, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

To actually be able to modify a System function I recommend [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/121):

```
SetAttributes[cases, HoldAll]

cases[args___] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Cases},
    SetAttributes[Cases, HoldFirst];
    Cases[args]
  ]

cases[1 + 3, _, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {1, 3}
> ```

This does not make additional definitions convenient however.  I am working on that.

---

### Experimental construct

I think this may be useful.  The idea is to have to associate `cases` with `Cases` only once, then be able to work with `cases` as desired.  It is limited to `DownValues` and `Attributes` for now as I cannot think of a clean way to extend it to `SubValues`, `UpValues`, etc.  That can probably be done with [`Stack`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Stack.html) but I am not as comfortable with that method as Leonid is so I shall leave it to a last resort.

```
SetAttributes[{clone, parent}, HoldAll]

clone[from_, to_] := Scan[(#[to] = #[from];) &, {DownValues, Attributes}]

parent[lhs_ -> rhs_] := (
  clone[lhs, rhs];
  Unprotect[rhs];
  x_rhs :=
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{rhs = lhs},
      Unprotect[lhs];
      clone[rhs, lhs];
      x
    ]
  )
```

Call it before definitions are made to `cases`:

```
parent[Cases -> cases];
```

Then add definitions to `cases` as desired:

```
SetAttributes[cases, HoldFirst]               (* test of Attributes *)

cases[a_, b_, "foo"] := cases[2^a, b, {-1}]   (* test of DownValues *)
```

Result:

```
cases[1 + 3, _, "foo"]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 3}
> ```

Comment: +1. I have to point out, that your experimental construct is very similar to the one I described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2795/81) - same ideas about double-cloning, and `Block`-ing.

Comment: @Leonid Fair enough.  I *did* link that thread in a **Related:** comment.  I starting working on this before looking at that, remembered you once wrote a `clone` function, looked at it and decided it was more complicated than I wanted here, and finished what you see above.  I have no doubt you could do this more robustly and probably include some `Stack` magic to provide full emulation, and I encourage you to do so if you have time.

Comment: Re: links - you are right, I haven't checked those. Although, given your answer, it would perhaps make more sense to mention them directly in it, but that's of course up to you. Besides, your construct is still different and used in a different context. Re: clone - there is actually a better way, exposed by Szabolcs [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19903/81).

Comment: @Leonid If I had based my code on yours I would have linked from within the answer as that's my standard practice.  (As I'm sure you've seen.)  `ExtendedFullDefinition` and friends don't work with core functions, correct?  So specifically not applicable here?

Comment: @Leonid Okay, I could at least use that to copy attributes and downvalues instead of my `clone`, but I'd need to change the `"ExcludedContexts"` option which ultimately makes it just as complex.

Comment: Re: links - yes, sure, that's why I said that your code and use case is different. I only meant that it would help link together similar approaches, not in any other sense. Re: core functions - yes, but I thought you take care of internal definitions via ``Internal`InheritedBlock``, while for top-level ones, I thought it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the comments, although I admit I don't understand some of your discussions and some of Mr.Wizard's answer. Feeling ashamed (-.-).