# Smart Pattern Test

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I defined two functions `f` and `g` which accept some argument which must be of some type, so I defined befor `MyTypeQ` that returns true if the pattern maches. Then the definitions:

```
f[var_?MyTypeQ]:= ...
```

this function is used *also* (but non only) to define `g`:

```
g[var_?MyTypeQ]:= (...) f[var] (...)
```

that is, `f` is used inside.

Now, since the test `MyTypeQ` can be a bit cumbersome, I would like to avoid to repeat it many times. I was wandering whether in the definition of `g` once `var` has passed the `MyTypeQ` test, is tested again by means of `f` that sits  inside the definition of `g`.

Is there an elegant method to avoid this without defining two version of `g` one "safe" (i.e. with `MyTypeQ` test) to be used outside `g` and the otehr "unsafe" (i.e. without `MyTypeQ` test) to be used inside `g`?

Comment: It does need because of the `(...)`

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can temporarily deactivate the definitions of the symbol `MyTypeQ` and define new ones, by using a `Block` construction for `g`. These new definitions are local to the `Block` and will be in effect at any point during the execution of its body. *(See for further details this [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BlocksAndLocalValues.html).)*

```
MyTypeQ[expr_] := (Pause[.5]; IntegerQ[expr]);

f[x_?MyTypeQ] := x;
g[x_?MyTypeQ] := Block[{MyTypeQ}, 

      (* new local definition *)
      MyTypeQ[_] := True; 

      (* body *)
      {x, f[x]}
];
```

Usage:

```
f[1] // AbsoluteTiming
(* uses the global definition of MyTypeQ *)
(* {0.494262, 1} *)

g[1] // AbsoluteTiming
(* uses the global definition of MyTypeQ for g and the local one for f *)
(* {0.491009, {1, 1}} *)

f[1] // AbsoluteTiming
(* still uses the global definition of MyTypeQ *)
(* {0.499528, 1} *)
```

---

***Update.*** The above code works fine when the function `f` is called only with argument `x` given to `g`. If called with another, it will give an incorrect result:

```
ClearAll[g];
g[x_?MyTypeQ] := Block[{MyTypeQ}, 
   MyTypeQ[_] := True;
   {x, f[x], f[x/2]}
];

g[1]
(* {1, 1, 1/2} *)
```

`g[1]` should return instead `{1, 1, f[1/2]}` since `1/2` does not yield `True` for the global definition.

An extension of the above code to account for such cases can be done with [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25769/what-does-internalinheritedblock-do). As `Block`, this symbol allows one to make temporary definitions; and unlike `Block`, original definitions are kept.

```
ClearAll[g];
g[x_?MyTypeQ] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{MyTypeQ},
     MyTypeQ[x] = True;
     {x, f[x], f[x/2]}
];
```

The local definition of `MyTypeQ` now applies only to `x`. This prevents the issue mentioned:

```
g[1] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.991258, {1, 1, f[1/2]}} *)
```

Here, the pattern test is evaluated twice (one for `g[1]` and one for `f[1/2]`), rather than 3 times (the evaluation for `f[1]` was avoided).

***Additional comments.*** With the last code we are effectively temporarily caching the result of `MyTypeQ[x]` during the evaluation of the body of `g`. The natural alternative that follows would be to cache permanently *all* values, as [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst) mentionned in his [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126164/smart-pattern-test/126171?noredirect=1#comment341476_126164).

```
ClearAll[MyTypeQ, f, g];
MyTypeQ[expr_] := MyTypeQ[expr] = (Pause[.5]; IntegerQ[expr]);

f[x_?MyTypeQ] := x;
g[x_?MyTypeQ] := {x, f[x], f[x/2]};

g[1] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.00844, {1, 1, f[1/2]}} *)
```

Prefering one or the other approach will depend on the body of `g` and how it is used. I quote the last paragraph of this [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html):

> There is of course a trade‐off involved in remembering values. It is faster to find a particular value, but it takes more memory space to store all of them. You should usually define functions to remember values only if the total number of different values that will be produced is comparatively small, or the expense of recomputing them is very great.

Comment: The problem here can occur when `g` calls e.g. `h[]` where `h` internally needs `MyTypeQ`. Nevertheless +1 ;)

Comment: Yes, there is actually another issue if `f` is called with another argument. I'm going to update my answer with an additional code.

Answer (score 7):

Is that fine? The trick is that once the test is passed the argument is wrapped with `MyType` so it should pass the test automatically.

```
f[MyType[var_]] := "f"
f[var_?MyTypeQ] := f[MyType[var]];

g[MyType[var_]] := {"g", f[MyType[var]] , "g"}
g[var_?MyTypeQ] := g[MyType[var]];


MyTypeQ[expr_] := (Pause[.5]; True)
```

---

```
f[1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.500496, "f"}
> ```

```
g[1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.500114, {"g", "f", "g"}}
> ```

Comment: @Xavier evaluation when?

Comment: @Xavier that was the point, only the functions that performed the test was supposed to wrap `MyType`. I've reverted old code because the shorter one would lead to MyType[MyType[...]] nesting in  general.

Comment: Yes, this was my point of concern. Didn't see the previous version, it is better I agree.

Comment: There is however still the issue that giving `MyType[var]` will pass the test, even though `var` may not pass the `MyTypeQ` test.

Comment: @Xavier yes but GIGO :)

Comment: Ahah, this is true :)