# Handling Missing values flexibly in Query (MissingBehavior problem)

Tags: replacement, associations, query, missing

There’s an inconsistency in how `Missing` values are imputed in `Query`, with `MissingBehavior->Automatic`.

consider a couple of functions packaged in an association:

```
asF = <|"class1" -> Function[{x}, x + 10],    "class2" -> Function[{x}, Boole[x > 1]]|>
```

and a data association:

```
as = <| "a" -> 1, "b" -> Missing[]|>
```

Then

```
as // Query[All, asF]   (* same as adding option MissingBehavior -> Automatic to Query  *)
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"class1" -> 11, "class2" -> 0|>,  "b" -> <|"class1" -> 10, "class2" -> Boole[Missing[] > 1]|>|>
> ```

So for the addition function ("class1") `Missing` is imputed as 0 but not in the `Boole` function (“class2”) .

Using `MissingBehavaior->None` is more consistent but not necessarily useful.

```
as // Query[All, asF, MissingBehavior -> None]
```

> <|"a" -> <|"class1" -> 11, "class2" -> 0|>,  "b" -> <|"class1" -> 10 + Missing[],    "class2" -> Boole[Missing[] > 1]|>|>

In some applications (eg when there's 100's of Boole's wrapped up in an `EmpiricalDistribution`, say) is it much more convenient to replace `Missing` whenever the as input argument is `Missing[...]`, ie: desired output:

> <|"a" -> <|"class1" -> 11, "class2" -> 0|>,  "b" -> <|"class1" -> Missing[],    "class2" -> Missing[] ]|>|>

`Query` has a `FailureAction` option “Replace” but not `MissingBehavior`. How can this functionality be emulated?

Answer (score 2):

Within the `Plus` function `Missing[...]` only acts as if it were zero.  Actually, it is taken to be `Sequence[]`.  The result is:

```
Plus[10]
(* 10 *)
```

... which gives the same result as `Plus[0, 10]`.  The functions which are subject to this "sequence" behaviour are listed in an internal variable (as of v11.3):

```
Dataset;    (* to trigger auto-loading *)
Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`$MissingIsSequenceP
(* Plus|Min|Max|MinMax *)
```

There are other interesting lists as well:

```
Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`$MissingIsIndeterminateP
(* Times | Minus | Power *)

Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`$PreserveMissingP
(* Counts|CountsBy|GroupBy|Take|Drop|Select|...|TakeLargestBy|TakeSmallestBy *)
```

In the expression `Boole[x > 1]`, it is the `Greater` function (rather than `Boole`) for which we desire special treatment.  Alas, neither `Greater` nor `Boole` receive special treatment by `MissingBehaviour`.

For fun, we could add `Greater` to `$MissingIsSequenceP` so that it gets the same behaviour as `Plus`:

```
AppendTo[Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`$MissingIsSequenceP, Greater]
```

So then:

```
as // Query[All, asF]
(* <| a -> <|class1 -> 11, class2 -> 0|>, b -> <|class1 -> 10, class2 -> 1|>|> *)
```

... but notice that the second `"class2"` is `1` instead of `0`.  This is because:

```
Greater[1]
(* True *)
```

If we *always* want an occurrence of `Missing` to be zero, we can take matters into our own hands:

```
Block[{Missing = 0&}
, as // Query[All, asF, MissingBehavior -> None]
]

(* <| a -> <|class1 -> 11, class2 -> 0|>, b -> <|class1 -> 10, class2 -> 0|>|> *)
```

or, somewhat more selectively:

```
Block[{Missing}
, Missing /: (f:Plus|Greater)[a___, m__Missing, b___] := f[a, 0, b]
; as // Query[All, asF, MissingBehavior -> None]
]
```

Note that it was necessary to turn off `MissingBehaviour` so that our overriding definitions of `Missing` would take effect.  This is a standard and supported way to make `Missing` behave however we like.

**Semi-unsanctioned Solution**

If we want the standard `MissingBehaviour -> Automatic` functionality to be supplemented with special rules for `Boole`, we can get more aggressive:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Boole}
, Unprotect[Boole]
; Boole[Except[True|False]] = 0
; as // Query[All, asF]
]

(* <| a -> <|class1 -> 11, class2 -> 0|>, b -> <|class1 -> 10, class2 -> 0|>|> *)
```

This is characterized as "semi-unsanctioned" because it uses [Internal`InheritedBlock](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/142) which is undocumented, but likely to remain around for a long time.

**Fully unsanctioned solution**

We could even go so far as to monkey-patch some internal definitions within the `Query` subsystem.  As of version 11.3, this would entail adding definitions as desired to this function:

```
Dataset;
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

PrintDefinitions[Dataset`Overrides`PackagePrivate`attachMissingUpvalues]
```

Or for query operators (not relevant to the present case):

```
PrintDefinitions[Dataset`ToMissingSafe]
```

However, these solutions are very brittle and likely to break in future versions.  I would recommend against using them.  Use the `Block[{Missing}, ...]` pattern instead.

Comment: First of all, why does `Greater[1]` evaluate at all given just one parameter...

Comment: Side-Q: Where should `MissingBehavior-> None` go here to result in the output `b->Missing[]`?  `<|"a" -> 2, "b" -> Missing[], "c" -> 10|> // 
 Query[{Identity, MinMax} /* 
   Replace[{data_, {min_, max_}} :> 
     Query[All, (# - min)/(max - min) &, MissingBehavior -> None][
      data]]]`

Comment: As to `Greater[1]`, ask WRI :)  As to the side-question, the closest we can get is to add `MissingBehavior->None` to the outer `Query` and replace `MinMax` with `Query[MinMax, MissingBehavior->Automatic]`.  Why?  Too large to fit into a comment :)  Suffice to say, the presence of `Replace` hides the inner subquery from the compiler so that the innermost `MissingBehavior->None` is ignored.  Bug?  To get all the way, we would need to also change the innermost function to `(# - min)/(max - min) & /* promoteMissing` where `promoteMissing[x_] := x /. m_ /; !FreeQ[m, _Missing] :> Missing[]`.