# ChartBaseStyle in BarChart3D - possible bug

Tags: bugs, charts

It looks like ChartBaseStyle in BarChart3D doesn't work in Grid mode when the matrix is larger than 9x9:

```
BarChart3D[RandomReal[1, {9, 9}], ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}], 
 BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}]
```

> [image]

```
BarChart3D[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}], 
 BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}]
```

[image]

Test done on mathematica 12 on MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an oversight in how `EdgeForm[None]` (the default for $\geq100$ bars) is handled when combining the different style directives for the bars<sup>1</sup>. Essentially, `EdgeForm[None]` overrides any explicit `EdgeForm` settings, which is why they are not applied in the second case (where there are $\geq100$ bars).

To circumvent this, you can execute the following code once before plotting anything:

```
Charting`iBarChart3D[{}];
prot = Unprotect@Charting`iBarChart3D;
DownValues@Charting`iBarChart3D = 
  DownValues@Charting`iBarChart3D /.
   HoldPattern[
     lhs : _["ChartBaseStyle"] = cd_[
       If[cond_,
        then_,
        else_
        ],
       rest__
       ]
     ] :> (
     If[cond,
      lhs = cd[rest];
      If[! MemberQ[lhs, _EdgeForm],
       AppendTo[lhs, then]
       ],
      lhs = cd[else, rest]
      ]
     );
Protect /@ prot;
```

Now the second example works as expected:

```
BarChart3D[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}], 
 BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}]
```

[image]

This works by modifying the way the default style for many bars in handled: Instead of simply adding `EdgeForm[None]` to the list of directives (which overrides any other specifications), we combine the remaining directives first. If no explicit `EdgeForm` directive is present, we manually append `EdgeForm[]` to the list.

<sup>1</sup>The relevant code is in `` Charting`iBarChart3D `` (look for `styleData["ChartBaseStyle"] = ...`; handles the default styles for the bars), `` Charting`ConstructDirective `` (handles the combining of the styles) and `` Charting`ConstructDirectiveOrNone `` (handles the override of `EdgeForm[None]`)

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Land , that worked perfectly. Do you reckon I should add the bug tag or is it an intended feature of the language?

Comment: I think it can be considered a bug - after all, it does work for less than 100 bars, and it doesn't really make sense to override the users choice. Btw, depending on what you want to do, [`DiscretePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html) may be more suited for your needs - it is something like the modern version of `BarChart3D`

Comment: Cheers, I'll play with DiscretePlot3D and see if it actually fits better my purposes. I've been using BarChart3D for about 5 years now, but I've honestly never been fully satisfied with it.

Answer (score 1):

The threshold of 100 bars is hard-coded  in `` Charting`iBarChart3D ``. In addition to its effect on styling as in OP, it also affects tooltips and highlighting of bars.

Fortunately, `100` appears only as the value of this threshold in `` Charting`iBarChart3D ``

```
Cases[DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D], _[___, _[___, 100, ___], ___], All]
```

> `` {If[System`BarChart3DDump`numberOfBars >= 100, 
>     System`BarChart3DDump`highlight = None; System`BarChart3DDump`labelingfunction = None], 
>   If[System`BarChart3DDump`numberOfBars >= 100, EdgeForm[], EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.5]]],
>    -(System`BarChart3DDump`numberOfBars/100)} ``

So you can define a  pre-processing function that replaces `100` with a larger value in `` Charting`iBarChart3D `` using `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` (see [this answer by rm-rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25771/125)):

```
preProcess = Function[x, Internal`InheritedBlock[{Charting`iBarChart3D}, 
   Unprotect[Charting`iBarChart3D]; 
   DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D] = DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D] /. 100 -> 200; x], 
   HoldFirst];
```

and wrap `BarChart3D` with  `preProcess`:

```
preProcess@BarChart3D[RandomReal[1, {12, 12}], 
    ChartLayout -> "Grid",
    ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}],
    BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can define your own `barChart3D` that takes the same arguments and options as `BarChart3D`:

```
barChart3D = Internal`InheritedBlock[{Charting`iBarChart3D},
   Unprotect[Charting`iBarChart3D];
   DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D] = DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D] /. 100 -> 200; 
   BarChart3D[##]] &;

barChart3D[RandomReal[1, {12, 12}], 
  ChartLayout -> "Grid",
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}],
  BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}]
```

> same picture

A better alternative may be to make this threshold an option rather than replacing the hard-coded threshold with another hard-coded one:

```
ClearAll[barChart3D]
Options[barChart3D] = Append[Options[BarChart3D], "Threshold" -> 100];
barChart3D[args__, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{Charting`iBarChart3D},
   Unprotect[Charting`iBarChart3D];
   DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D] = DownValues[Charting`iBarChart3D] /. 
     100 -> OptionValue["Threshold"]; 
   BarChart3D[args, FilterRules[{o}, Options[BarChart3D]]]];
```

***Example:***

```
Row[{barChart3D[RandomReal[1, {12, 12}], ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}],
   BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}, ImageSize -> 400], 
  barChart3D[RandomReal[1, {12, 12}], ChartLayout -> "Grid",
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thickness[.01], Opacity[1]}],
   BarSpacing -> {0.7, 0.7}, ImageSize -> 400, 
   "Threshold" -> 200]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Note:** If you want to suppress tooltips and bar highlighting you can always use `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.