# How does one clear the memory of a recursive function

Tags: functions, recursion, memoization

I want to implement the recursive function

```
 v[n_] := v[n] = v[n-1] + f[n-1] + Random[NormalDistribution[0,s]]
```

to get `vel = {v[0], v[1],..., v[N]}`.

I want to compute $M$ replicates of `vel`.  How do I clear the memory of $v$ after each replicate of `vel`?  If I don't I get the same vel repeated $M$ times.

Comment: does your recursion have a base case?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I think this should be reopened, because the best way to deal with this is not, IMO, clearing `DownValues`.

Comment: @Pillsy, why wouldn't it be an appropriate answer for the other question?

Comment: Anyway, here's how to clear selected values: `Scan[Composition[Unset, v], {2, 3, 7, 8}]`. You can use `Range[n]` as the list of values to clear, thus leaving `v[0]` and the general rule.

Comment: @J.M., I don't think so, since the reasons for clearing are different. There it was about resource use, here it's about resetting the computation each time so different `RandomVariate`s are generated.

Comment: Then the post should be edited to reflect that, @Pillsy. With just the title and the last two sentences, it reads like a dupe of the other.

Comment: Just for completeness: recursion is absolutely unnecessary in the OP's presented case: `Accumulate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, s], n]]`.

Comment: @J.M. : I don't see that this captures the calls to `f[]`.  However, something equally terse should work.

Comment: @Eric, well, two `Accumulate[]`'s should do the trick in that case; I just wanted to give the OP an alternate view.

Comment: Related: [(19536)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19536/121), [(41942)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41942/121)

Answer (score 15):

#### Suggested solution

If I understood the question right, then the simplest solution here would probably be to define a helper function like the following:

```
vv[n_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{v}, v /@ Range[n]];
```

Then, you get

```
vel = vv[m]
```

and every run of `vv` would result in different set of values, while the values in the set will all come from the same memoization "run".

The presence of `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` guarantees that whatever values were remembered inside of it, will be cleared automatically when the execution leaves the block.

#### Example

For example:

```
ClearAll[f, v, s, vv];
s = 1;
f[x_] := x;
v[0] := 0;
v[n_] := v[n] = v[n - 1] + f[n - 1] + Random[NormalDistribution[0, s]];
vv[n_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{v}, v /@ Range[n]];
```

Test:

```
vv[10]

(* {-0.0712327, 1.67558, 4.93819, 9.21973, 13.7199, 17.3607, 22.7843, 31.0941, 37.9027, 47.6244} *)

vv[10]

(* {-3.29625, -2.51668, -0.464889, 1.71271, 4.70297, 9.78192, 15.8081, 22.5965, 29.3856, 38.323} *)
```

#### Links

Closely related questions:

- [dynamic-programming-in-mathematica-how-to-automatically-localize-and-or-clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342748/dynamic-programming-in-mathematica-how-to-automatically-localize-and-or-clear)
- [how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/how-to-clear-parts-of-a-memoized-function)

Comment: `Array[v, n]` could be used, too. Is there any reason why ``Internal`InheritedBlock[]`` is necessary here?

Comment: @J.M. I added the explanation to the post. The reason is to clear the memoized values, after each run.

Comment: I didn't see this answer before I wrote [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231208/43522) where I automate the process of storing and clearing cached values with a wrapper function.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Sure thing (it is hard to know about all the answers, probably impossible). I wouldn't vote it up if I didn't think it had novel parts, too :). I don't think there is an exact answer like yours anywhere on the site (although as I said, there are bits and pieces scattered), and I think your answer is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to define the collection of `v`s when you produce a realization of `vel`, so I'd replace this with

```
vel[n_] := Module[{},
  Table[
    v[k] = v[k - 1] + f[k - 1] + Random[NormalDistribution[0, s]],
  {k, 0, n}]
]
```

This generates a new set of `v`s every time you call `vel[]`.  (The bulk of this could be replaced by `NestList[]`, but I'm not convinced it buys much to do so.)  You don't give any hints about the base case of your recursion, about `s`, or about what `f` does, so

```
Block[{s = 1},
  Print[vel[3]];
  Print[v[2]];
  Print[v[2]];
  Print[vel[3]];
]
v[2]
(*  {-1.39483+f[-1]+v[-1],-1.17269+f[-1]+f[0]+v[-1],-0.19439+f[-1]+f[0]+f[1]+v[-1],0.863082 +f[-1]+f[0]+f[1]+f[2]+v[-1]}  *)
(*  -0.19439+f[-1]+f[0]+f[1]+v[-1]  *)
(*  -0.19439+f[-1]+f[0]+f[1]+v[-1]  *)
(*  {-0.811165+f[-1]+v[-1],-0.959559+f[-1]+f[0]+v[-1],-2.25842+f[-1]+f[0]+f[1]+v[-1],-1.75508+f[-1]+f[0]+f[1]+f[2]+v[-1]}  *)
(*  -2.25842 + f[-1] + f[0] + f[1] + v[-1]  *)
```

The `v`s keep their values between calls to `vel[]` and change on each call to `vel[]`.  If you want to reuse a `vel` without changing the `v`s, store it.